# Getting difference between data in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Student table in my sqlserver 2008 with following data:

[image]

Now when I provide two dates (eg. from date as '2015-1-1' and to date as '2015-3-1') I should get the difference of sum for the specific dates not sum of total in between dates

> Difference between(sum(total marks) for 2015-3-1 and sum(total marks) for 2015-1-1)

i.e Difference(sum(54,80), sum(60,58)) which is 134 - 118 = 16

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to do this.

```
SELECT  Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN Date = '2015-1-1' THEN TotalMarks ELSE 0 END), 0) - 
                 Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN Date = '2015-3-1' THEN TotalMarks ELSE 0 END), 0)
FROM   Student
```

Comment: @NoDisplayName thanks a ton. This was exactly what I was looking for, Conditional Aggregate for performance smoothness. I have another requirement which is slightly more complex. After trying it out myself, if I'm unable I will post it as a question. If possible please help me with that one. I would be grateful..

Comment: @NoDisplayName can you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107952/using-conditional-aggregate-in-sqlserver-2008) please

Answer (score 3):

Use this query

```
DECLARE @result AS INTEGER

SET @result = ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TotalMarks) FROm Student WHERE Date = '2015-1-1'), 0) - 
           ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TotalMarks) FROm Student WHERE Date = '2015-3-1'), 0)


SELECT @result
```

Comment: Thanks @Kumar but a small doubt, do I need to declare 'result' variable? I mean can't I bind it inside select statement because simultaneous to this I'm also executing other queries. So will it hinder the performance? guide me please

Comment: @user2470766: Select query returns single row  or more?

Comment: actually I have simplified the requirement here. My actual query is a bit complex. But yea for the asked question your query served the purpose so thanks a lot. I will post a different question for my real requirement....