# Using Conditional Aggregate in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had a query with too many select statements. Hence I used **conditional aggregation**. The query refers the data from **Instock** table in SQL Server 2008 and the final query looks like:

```
select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2013-8-1' THEN CurrentStock ELSE 0 END) as CurrentStock,
    Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2014-2-1' THEN CPU ELSE 0 END), 0) - Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2013-8-1' THEN CPU ELSE 0 END), 0) as CPU,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Month = '2013-8-1' THEN NonCPUWIP ELSE 0 END) as NonCPU,
    Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2014-2-1' THEN ScrapDiscarded ELSE 0 END), 0) - Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2013-8-1' THEN ScrapDiscarded ELSE 0 END), 0) as Scrap,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Month = '2013-8-1' THEN WaitingForApproval ELSE 0 END) as WFA  
from 
    Instock
where 
    Vendor = 'abc'
```

The issue is the one last query which needs to be included. It gets the data from `OutStock` table but I want to include that query in the above one so that it returns result as single row. Im able to meet the requirement using nested query but I want the same result using **conditional aggregation** for database performance smoothness.

The query that needs to be included is:

```
select 
    COUNT(Product) as Despatched 
from 
    OutStock 
where 
    DispatchDate between '2013-8-1' and '2014-2-1' 
    and Vendor = 'abc'`
```

So combining both I want to execute as a single query which will return a single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the second query in the column list of first query since it is going to return only one row. Try this.

```
SELECT Sum(CASE
             WHEN MONTH = '2013-8-1' THEN CurrentStock
             ELSE 0
           END)                                 AS CurrentStock,
       Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2014-2-1' THEN CPU ELSE 0 END), 0) - 
       Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2013-8-1' THEN CPU ELSE 0 END), 0) AS CPU,
       Sum(CASE WHEN Month = '2013-8-1' THEN NonCPUWIP ELSE 0 END) AS NonCPU,
       Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2014-2-1' THEN ScrapDiscarded ELSE 0 END), 0) - 
       Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2013-8-1' THEN ScrapDiscarded ELSE 0 END), 0)AS Scrap,
       Sum(CASE WHEN Month = '2013-8-1' THEN WaitingForApproval ELSE 0 END) AS WFA,
       (SELECT Count(STBSerialNUMBER)
        FROM   OutStock
        WHERE  DispatchDate BETWEEN '2013-8-1' AND '2014-2-1'
                AND Vendor = 'abc' ) as Despatched
FROM   Instock I
WHERE  Vendor = 'abc'
```

**Update :**

If you want the result count of each model then convert the `subquery` it to  `correlated subquery`. should be something like

```
  (SELECT Count(STBSerialNUMBER)
   FROM   OutStock O
   WHERE o.model = i.model  -- here is the change
   AND O.DispatchDate BETWEEN '2013-8-1' AND '2014-2-1'
   AND o.Vendor = 'abc')
```

Here for each `model` in `Instock` table the respective `count` in the `outstock` will be caluclated.

Or you can also use `Left Join`. First calculate  the count of each `model` in `Outstock` table `join` the result back to the `Instock` table using the model

```
   ....
   From Instock I Left Join 
   (SELECT Count(STBSerialNUMBER) OutStock_count,Model
   FROM   OutStock O
   WHERE  O.DispatchDate BETWEEN '2013-8-1' AND '2014-2-1'
   AND o.Vendor = 'abc'
   Group by Model) O on o.model = i.model
```

Comment: thanks again mate. It worked just fine. Only place where you can get your doubts cleared in a span....Thanks again :) :)

Comment: what if my inner select query returns multiple row say what If I want to group the result from OutStock table model wise and reflect the same in my resultant table along with the Instock data? Thanks in advance

Comment: @KC - Don't mention it

Comment: @ NoDisplayName can you please help me out [here??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914184/extracting-data-by-matching-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-2008/28914824?noredirect=1#comment46100682_28914824)