# Extracting data by matching multiple tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to extract result based on match from multiple tables, three tables to be specific. The tables are **`Despatch`**, **`Activation`** and **`Replaced`**. Diagram below shows structure and sample data in them.

[image]

The Expected result based on above diagram is:

```
LotQty | ApprovedQty | DispatchDate | Installed
  15   |      10     |   2013-8-7   |    9
```

The result should be on following criteria:

**LotQty, ApprovedQty** and **DispatchDate** are just count and distinct from `Despatch` table

**Installed**(Real Problem). This field is based on calculation:

1. Query should first match **`SerialNo`** from **`Despatch`** table for Lot 20 with **`SerialNo`** under Lot 20 in **`Activation`** table. It finds 8 match ignoring Product1&2 which have different Lot quantities.
2. Next for 8 matched SerialNo's it should compare date. If **`DispatchDate`** for a **`SerialNo`** is less than **`ActivationDate`** then it is count as 1.(Product3's **`DispatchDate`** is greater than **`ActivationDate`**. Hence it is ignored. For rest of the SerialNo's **`DispatchDate`** is < **`ActivationDate`**). So total resultant count from **`Activation`** table is 7.
3. For unmatched SerialNo's from **`Despatch`** table (Product1,2 & 3) it should perform a match in **`Replaced`** table. It finds match for all the SerialNo's but as Product4 to Product10 are already matched from **`Activation`**, here it should match only 3 leftover SerialNo's(Product1,2 & 3). Product1 & 2 matches here. Next similar to above it should check if **`DispatchDate`** is < **`RecordDate`**. Both Product1 & 2 have **`DispatchDate` < `RecordDate`** so count from **`Replaced`** table is 2.
4. Now the total **`Installed`** should be 9 (7 from **`Activation`** table and 2 from **`Replaced`** table).

There can be multiple entries of a **`SerialNo`** from **`Desptach`** in both **`Replaced`** and **`Activation`** table as observed in above diagram . So first the match of SerialNo's of **`Despatch`** table should be done with **`Activation`** table and if any of **`SerialNo`** is unmatched or it's **`DispatchDate` > `ActivationDate`** only then for those SerialNo's it should go ahead to find a match in **`Replaced`** table.

So far with the help of [@ jpw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175077/jpw) I have managed to form a query as below :

```
select
(
    select distinct LOTQty
    from Despatch
    where LotQty = '15'
)as LotQty

,(
    select COUNT(SerialNo)
    from Despatch
    where LotQty = '15'
)as ApprovedQty

,(
    select distinct(DispatchDate)
    from Despatch
    where LotQty = '15'
)as DispatchDate

,(
    select COUNT(A.SerialNo) + count(R.NewSerialNo)
    from Despatch D
    left join
        Activation A
        on D.SerialNo = A.SerialNo
        and D.DispatchDate <= A.ActivationDate
        and D.LotQty = A.LotQty
    left join
        Replaced R
        on D.SerialNo = R.NewSerialNo
        and D.DispatchDate <= R.RecordDate
)as Installed
```

which yields wrong output i.e :

```
LotQty | ApprovedQty | DispatchDate | Installed
  15   |      10     |   2013-8-7   |    17
```

Help is deeply appreciated, 
Thanks in advance

**EIDT1**
[image]

So from above diagram even now the `Installed` should be 9 as I would like result only for Lot15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your Replaced data. Looking at your condition, it's matching all of the records that are in that table that match the serial number in the Dispatch table. You indicate it should only be 2 though. You are missing a condition that would indicate that it's unmatched in Activation to narrow the results.

Ensuring that A's SerialNo in the second join should do the trick for you

```
select
(
    select distinct LOTQty
    from Despatch
    where LotQty = '15'
)as LotQty

,(
    select COUNT(SerialNo)
    from Despatch
    where LotQty = '15'
)as ApprovedQty

,(
    select distinct(DispatchDate)
    from Despatch
    where LotQty = '15'
)as DispatchDate

,(
    select COUNT(A.SerialNo) + count(R.NewSerialNo)
    from Despatch D
    left join
        Activation A
        on D.SerialNo = A.SerialNo
        and D.DispatchDate <= A.ActivationDate
        and D.LotQty = A.LotQty
    left join
        Replaced R
        on D.SerialNo = R.NewSerialNo
        and D.DispatchDate <= R.RecordDate
        and A.SerialNo IS NULL
    where D.LotQty = '15'
)as Installed
```

I can't seem to login to SQLFiddle right now, so here is the schema you need if you want to try it out.

```
CREATE TABLE Despatch (
    SerialNo VARCHAR(20),
    DispatchDate DATETIME,
    LOTQty INT )

CREATE TABLE Activation (
    SerialNo VARCHAR(20),
    LOTQty INT,
    ActivationDate DATETIME )

CREATE TABLE Replaced (
    NewSerialNo VARCHAR(20),
    RecordDate DATETIME )

INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product1', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product2', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product3', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product4', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product5', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product6', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product7', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product8', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product9', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product10', '2013-08-07', 15)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product11', '2013-08-07', 20)
INSERT INTO Despatch
VALUES ('Product12', '2013-08-07', 20)

INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product1', 55, '2013-07-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product2', 20, '2013-11-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product3', 15, '2013-07-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product4', 15, '2013-11-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product5', 15, '2013-11-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product6', 15, '2013-11-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product7', 15, '2013-11-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product8', 15, '2013-11-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product9', 15, '2013-11-13')
INSERT INTO Activation
VALUES ('Product10', 15, '2013-11-13')

INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product1', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product2', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product4', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product5', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product6', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product7', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product8', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product9', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product10', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product11', '2013-12-07')
INSERT INTO Replaced
VALUES ('Product12', '2013-12-07')
```

Comment: @ Brian Dishaw thanks for giving a hand here. I changed my query with update of your's but it still gives answer as 10 for Installed instead of desired 9. Also I'm not getting the last "left join" part. It's checking for A.SerialNo is null. I have few serial no's of Despatch table which didn't found a match in Activation. Those Serial no's should only be matched with Replaced talbe. I'm not sure if that's what your query is doing, It narrowed down the result though...Please see if you could help me get desired output...

Comment: Also for the Installed column it is checking for all LotQty that are equal in both Despatch and Activation table (D.LotQty = A.LotQty in first left join). So even if I give Lot as 20 it will still match for all Lots which are matching in Despatch and Activation table

Comment: When I run this on sqlfiddle.com with the schema and inserts that match you example, I get 9 installed back. Are you looking at different data than your example?

Comment: The A.SerialNo is null in the second join will give you only matches for those that DO NOT match in the first join. If you omit that, then you will always match as both in the Despatch as well as the Activation tables.

Comment: I still can't seem to login to sqlfiddle to share, but here is a screenshot of the results I'm seeing. http://screencast.com/t/oVXILuQV

Comment: Im sorry @ Brian actually my data had a null value added at end. So it returned 10 as Installed. But when I removed it, result was 9. But my query is in first left join we never specified specific "LotQty". So if it found a match other than Lot15 then it would return count of that entry too. Refer my Edit1. If I want result for Lot15 it would still calculate count including lot 20 and give result as 11

Comment: See my edit for the additional where clause for limiting the lotqty.

Comment: @KC Using Brians test data I get 10 approved and 9 installed for lot 15 using the query in my original answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28855348/1175077 so I still don't understand what's wrong with it...

Comment: @ Brian issue was with my Database. Both your's n jpw's query did get me the desired result....So thank you